# java scrip object don't call function inside it

Tags: function, class, logging, console

What's wrong with this code? i wantet to print message into cnsole within function inside class.

```
function Clas(x);
{
   this.x = x;
function nothing()
{
    console.log(x);
}
}
var clas = new Clas(1);
clas.nothing();
```

Answer (score 0):

`nothing()` isn't exposed. You'll need to attach it to `this`.

```
function Something(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.nothing = function() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
}

var something = new Something(3);
something.nothing(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Want something like this?
You can return a `JSON` object containing a function. (So it is a little bit more like OOP.)

```
function Clas(x) {
    return {
        x : x,
        nothing : function () {
            console.log(x);
        }
    }
}

var clas = new Clas(1);
clas.nothing();
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juy2jdkp/